# How to multiply N-demensional tensors correctly using tf.einsum?

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-algebra, tensor

In my problem, I have a batch of matrices, represented by a tensor of shap [BATCH,SEQUENCE,DATA]. I have a function to transform the last axis of this tensor into cartesian coordinates. It was first implemented in pure Python and then I implemented in TF.

Originally the function performed the calculations over a single element of the batch tensor. But now (code below) it is able to be applied over the batch axis. If I input only one example to the function (x = (1,SEQUENCE,DATA)), the function works properly. When the number of examples (BATCH > 1) grows, the function does not work properly, making a wrong calculation.

I already tested with both the original numpy function and the TF implementation. And i narrowed down to the tf.einsum call. What is wrong in here and how can I change this behavior?

```
def z2c(zmat):
    cartesian = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(tf.shape(zmat)))

    seq_length = zmat.shape[1]

    batch = zmat.shape[0]
    bead_1 = tf.constant([[zmat[i,1,0], 0., 0] for i in range(batch)])
    cartesian[:,1,:].assign(bead_1)
    bead_2 =             
      [[(zmat[i,2,0]*np.sin(zmat[i,2,1]))+zmat[i,1,0],zmat[i,2,0]*np.cos(zmat[i,2,1]), 0] \
          for i in range(batch)]
    cartesian[:,2,:].assign(bead_2)

    r, theta, phi = zmat[:,:,0], zmat[:,:,1], zmat[:,:,2]

    sinTheta = np.sin(theta)
    cosTheta = np.cos(theta)
    sinPhi = np.sin(phi)
    cosPhi = np.cos(phi)

    x = r * cosTheta
    y = r * cosPhi * sinTheta
    z = r * sinPhi * sinTheta
    xyz = tf.Variable([-x,y,z])

    xyz = tf.transpose(tf.Variable([-x,y,z]), (1,2,0))

    def extend(cartesian, xyz, i):#, x,y,z):
        cartesian = tf.Variable(cartesian)
        a,b,c = cartesian[:,i-3,:], cartesian[:,i-2,:], cartesian[:,i-1,:]
    
        print("Iter: {}".format(i))
        print('a: {}, b: {}, c: {}\n'.format(a,b,c))
        print(a.shape)

        ab = (b - a)
        bc = (c - b) #.normalized()

        bc = bc/tf.linalg.norm(bc)

        n = tf.linalg.cross(ab,bc) 
        n = n/tf.linalg.norm(n)
        ncbc = tf.linalg.cross(n,bc)

        M = tf.Variable([[bc[:,0], ncbc[:,0], n[:,0]],                                     
        [bc[:,1], ncbc[:,1], n[:,1]], [bc[:,2], ncbc[:,2], n[:,2]]])


        pos = xyz[:,i,:]

        cartesian[:,i,:].assign( tf.einsum('bsc,bs->bc', tf.transpose(M), xyz[:,i,:]) + c )

        return cartesian, xyz, i+1
    def cond(cartesian, xyz, i):
   
        return i < seq_len


    i = tf.Variable(3, dtype=tf.int32)
    seq_len = tf.Variable(seq_length,dtype=tf.int32)
    result, _, _ = tf.while_loop(cond = cond,
                      body = extend,
                      loop_vars = (cartesian, xyz, i))


    return result
```

Comment: Quick comment : You should not use `tf.Variable` like you are doing. tf.Variable are used to define variable that should have a state, i.e parameters that will be learned during training. ([Read more about tf.Variable](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/variable).  It contributes to make your code hard to read.

Comment: Hey!! Thanks for the comment, and I changed the code. Now I have another error and should post another question.